# How to move 2D Object within camera view boundary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene that my camera doesn't follow my player. When player reaches the end of camera I want player to can't go further (out of camera view). How can I do this?

My codes for movement

```
public class PlayerBlueController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
private float x;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") / 100 * speed;
    transform.Translate (x,0,0);

}
}
```

As you can see from this. It gets out of camera's view.
[image]

Comment: Place two empty game objects at each extreme corner (bottom left, top right). Then use their positions to clamp the user movement. Or if you just move in one dimension like you seem, x = Mathf.Clamp(x, minX, maxX);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you used a Collider2D. *You should be using `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition` instead of `transform.Translate`* or you'll likely run into issues when `transform.Translate` is used.

**1**.Take the final move position and convert it to new position in ViewPortPoint with `Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint`

**2**.Apply a limit with `Mathf.Clamp` to the result in **#1**.

**3**.Convert the ViewPortPoint back to world point with `Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint`.

**4**.Finally, move it with `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`.

---

The code below is modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760846/how-to-move-2d-object-with-wasd-in-unity) answer to include restriction to screen boundary.

**Move without `Rigidbody`**:

*Use only if collision and physics are NOT required:*

```
public float speed = 100;
public Transform obj;

public void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    //Move only if we actually pressed something
    if ((h > 0 || v > 0) || (h < 0 || v < 0))
    {
        Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(h, v, 0);
        tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;


        Vector3 newPos = obj.transform.position + tempVect;
        checkBoundary(newPos);
    }
}

void checkBoundary(Vector3 newPos)
{
    //Convert to camera view point
    Vector3 camViewPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(newPos);

    //Apply limit
    camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.x, 0.04f, 0.96f);
    camViewPoint.y = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.y, 0.07f, 0.93f);

    //Convert to world point then apply result to the target object
    obj.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(camViewPoint);
}
```

**Move Object with `Rigidbody2D`**:

Use if collision and physics are required:

```
public float speed = 100;
public Rigidbody2D rb;

public void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    //Move only if we actually pressed something
    if ((h > 0 || v > 0) || (h < 0 || v < 0))
    {
        Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(h, v, 0);
        tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + tempVect);

        Vector3 newPos = rb.transform.position + tempVect;
        checkBoundary(newPos);
    }
}

void checkBoundary(Vector3 newPos)
{
    //Convert to camera view point
    Vector3 camViewPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(newPos);

    //Apply limit
    camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.x, 0.04f, 0.96f);
    camViewPoint.y = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.y, 0.07f, 0.93f);

    //Convert to world point then apply result to the target object
    Vector3 finalPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(camViewPoint);
    rb.MovePosition(finalPos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really helpful.
I want to ask something. What exactly mathf.clamp do? because when i change the numbers 0.04f 0.96f player just sticks one side of the camera. what are those numbers? I didn't catch the logic behind it. 
And one question about movement. When I release the button player keeps going some little time. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Use `Input.GetAxisRaw` instead of `Input.GetAxis`  to make it stop right away or set the `Rigidbody.velocity to `Vector3.zero` to stop it right away. The screen viewport has a value between 0(left) to 1(right) on the x- axis.`0.04f` is min value you want the object to be on the x axis.  `0.96f` is max value you want the object to be on the x value. You can make those public variables and modify them in the Editor until you get the perfect value that determines the min/max for your object position on the screen.

Comment: For example, `public float min = 0.04f;` and `public float max = 0.96f;`  then you can use  `camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.x, min, max);`. From the editor you can use modify min and max until you get the perfect value you want.

Comment: Everything works perfectly. But one thing. I have to change Input.GetAxisRaw to Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) and make this a AddForce. Because I want to use my a,d keys and arrow keys on different purposes. I was able to do this but I can't limit the player now with the same thing. Should I do something else than using getkey-addforce to use wasd and arrow keys or do i need to change the method completely to limit the player movement?

Comment: I suggest you still use `MovePosition` instead of `AddForce`. Simply remove `Input.GetAxis` then replace the `h` and `v`    from `Vector3(h, v, 0);` with `0` and `1`. Use `1` when pressed(`Input.GetKey`) and `0` when released(`Input.GetKeyUp`). Ask a new question for that since this question used `Input.GetAxis`. I will take a look at it. I may be out for hours when I return I will take a look. Don't forget to post your current code if you create new question.

Answer (score 0):

image not respond .
but you can check player location

```
x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") / 100 * speed;
if(gameobject.transform.x > someValue)
    x=0
```

gameobject will be OBJECT in scene that u attach class to it.

another way is place 2 empty gameobject with collider as invisibleWall and get collider to player

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is:

1.Get the coordinates of your screen cornes (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right). You can get this coordinates using [Screen.height and Screen.width](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html).

2.Convert this coordinates using the camera you need with [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

3.Get your player coordinates and check that they are inside the rect which is formed by 4 coordinates of the screen corners.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit your transform's position based on the edges of the camera. [Here is an answer describing the different coordinate systems in unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/256817/about-world-space-and-local-space.html)

You're probably looking to do something like this:

```
float xMin = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero).x;
float xMax = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.one).x;

Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;
float dx = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") / 100 * speed;
Vector3 desiredPos = new Vector3(currentPos.x + dx, currentPos.y, currentPos.z);

Vector3 realPos = desiredPos;

if(desiredPos.x > xMax)
    realPos.x = xMax;
else if(desiredPos.x < xMin)
    realPos.x = xMin;

transform.position = realPos;
```

[Read up here for more info on ViewportToWorldPoint(), it's extremely useful to become comfortable with the different coordinate spaces and how you can convert between them.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html)