# How to move multiple players with WASD and arrow keys within camera view boundary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I with this code below I can move my character and limit it to the camera view. But since I'm using input `Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");` my character moves both with a-d keys and arrow keys. But I want arrow keys for another character.
I tried `AddForce` (which is I don't prefer for character moves) with an if statement to use specific keys. But I wasn't able to use my codes to check boundary. Can you suggest anything? (Btw my character only moves horizontally)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerBlueController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Rigidbody2D player1rb;
    public float viewpointfirst;
    public float viewpointsecond; 


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        if((horizontal > 0) ||  (horizontal < 0)) 
        {
            Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3 (horizontal, 0, 0);
            tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 newPos = player1rb.transform.position + tempVect;
            checkBoundary (newPos);
        }
    }




    void checkBoundary(Vector3 newPos)
    {
        Vector3 camViewPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint (newPos);
        camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp (camViewPoint.x, viewpointfirst, viewpointsecond);
        Vector3 finalPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint (camViewPoint);
        player1rb.MovePosition (finalPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: use getkey A and D for one player, use keyboard arrows for another player ? Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) for more info

Comment: Yes but getkey and what? If i combine getkey and addforce I can't use my checkboundary funtion to limit character's movement.

Comment: There should be alot of options to move the character that you can find online. Transform.position, transform.translate those are the few ones that i can think right now, although they have different behaviours which might suit your game or not. There is also simple move that you can search.

Comment: Also to limit your characters in a specific area, you can use emptyGameobjects with colliders attached to them, use those as walls but invisible for player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified my old [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057183/3785314) to use `Input.GetKey` instead of `Input.GetAxisRaw`. All you had to do was replace the horizontal variable from `Vector3 (horizontal, 0, 0);` with `-1` when going left, `1` when going right and `0` when not pressed at-all. The rest of the code remains the-same. I added more functions to prevent writing the-same code multiple times because you want *player 1* and *player 2* to use different keys which requires identical code.

WASD for *player 1* and arrow keys for *player 2*. You can change these around to whatever keys you want in the `Update` function where `movePlayer` is called.

```
public float speed = 50;

public Rigidbody2D rb1;

public Rigidbody2D rb2;

public void Update()
{
    //Player one (WASD)
    movePlayer(rb1, KeyCode.A, KeyCode.D, KeyCode.W, KeyCode.S);

    //Player two (Arrow keys)
    movePlayer(rb2, KeyCode.LeftArrow, KeyCode.RightArrow, KeyCode.UpArrow, KeyCode.DownArrow);
}

void movePlayer(Rigidbody2D targetRg, KeyCode left, KeyCode right, KeyCode up, KeyCode down)
{
    Vector2 hAndV = getInput(targetRg, left, right, up, down);

    Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(hAndV.x, hAndV.y, 0);
    tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 newPos = targetRg.transform.position + tempVect;
    checkBoundary(targetRg, newPos);
}

Vector2 getInput(Rigidbody2D targetRg, KeyCode left, KeyCode right, KeyCode up, KeyCode down)
{
    Vector2 input = Vector4.zero;

    //Horizontal
    if (Input.GetKey(left))
        input.x = -1;
    else if (Input.GetKey(right))
        input.x = 1;
    else
    {
        input.x = 0;
        targetRg.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        targetRg.angularVelocity = 0f;
    }

    //Vertical
    if (Input.GetKey(up))
        input.y = 1;
    else if (Input.GetKey(down))
        input.y = -1;
    else
    {
        input.y = 0;
        targetRg.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        targetRg.angularVelocity = 0f;
    }

    return input;
}

void checkBoundary(Rigidbody2D targetRg, Vector3 newPos)
{
    //Convert to camera view point
    Vector3 camViewPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(newPos);

    //Apply limit
    camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.x, 0.04f, 0.96f);
    camViewPoint.y = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.y, 0.07f, 0.93f);

    //Convert to world point then apply result to the target object
    Vector3 finalPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(camViewPoint);
    targetRg.MovePosition(finalPos);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to use the Axis still, you could always edit them in the `Input` project settings.

Comment: @GMR516 I've seen people that do this. I just want the Axis to be left as the default values. I've seen several new users that modified the Axis then couldn't get other Unity tutorials to work with the Axis because they modified it. Just trying to prevent that

Comment: True. If they're very beginner-ish I guess it's best not to mess with that stuff.