# UNITY 2d Convert Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") to Touch Drag with Width Control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, 2d

```
public float speed = 15f;
public float mapWidth = 5f;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;
     Vector2 newPosition = rb.position + Vector2.right * x;
     newPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, -mapWidth, mapWidth);
     rb.MovePosition(newPosition);
 }
```

How do you change the code in *FixedUpdate()* be in **touch control for MOBILE**. so when I drag the object(my player) it will follow in the Horizontal axis only BUT! it will not go off the boundaries of the camera but also controllable width like in this code. If the number is high in mapWidth it will only move a little left and right.

Comment: What do you mean by "boundaries"?

Comment: the screen has a playable area. Like a ring.Square sprite thing. the player should not be able to go off that.

Comment: You mean screen boundary? They don't go off the screen?

Comment: Yes. Yes that's it.

Comment: Ok. See the answer from the duplicate. The first part is a non rigidbody solution. You need to read the second part of the answer which uses rigidbody.

Comment: is this for touch? I wanted to change the one I posted into touch control. draggable object using touch for mobile.

Comment: I just re-opened it. Didn't see the mobile touch part

Comment: You can easily convert it to touch but I don't think it will give you the expected outcome. What is this code supposed to do when you touch the screen? You do need to explain that.

Comment: Ok, My bad I didn't explain it well but I have used this code:

if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
         Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
         transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);
        }

It's working Horizontal but still go off the camera. If possible I want to be able use the "mapWidth" to control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056763/how-to-move-2d-object-within-camera-view-boundary) question shows how to move object and apply boundary on the screen with `WorldToViewportPoint`.

You can add touch support to it by adding `Input.touches.deltaPosition.x` and `Input.touches.deltaPosition.y` under the `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")`.

With both boundary and Input support added, below is what it should look like:

```
public float speed = 100;
public Rigidbody2D rb;

public void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    //Add touch support
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        h = touch.deltaPosition.x;
        v = touch.deltaPosition.y;
    }

    //Move only if we actually pressed something
    if ((h > 0 || v > 0) || (h < 0 || v < 0))
    {
        Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(h, v, 0);
        tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + tempVect);

        Vector3 newPos = rb.transform.position + tempVect;
        checkBoundary(newPos);
    }
}

void checkBoundary(Vector3 newPos)
{
    //Convert to camera view point
    Vector3 camViewPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(newPos);

    //Apply limit
    camViewPoint.x = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.x, 0.04f, 0.96f);
    camViewPoint.y = Mathf.Clamp(camViewPoint.y, 0.07f, 0.93f);

    //Convert to world point then apply result to the target object
    Vector3 finalPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(camViewPoint);
    rb.MovePosition(finalPos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This work and I just removed the Vertical control for this. now its really what I needed Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I was able to help